# Show Authors in a Page Based on Selected Metadata

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a new project where registered users can select multiple careers in the User Profile page in wordpress Admin. I have been able to add the check boxes of different careers to the User profile page which registered users can check/select.

At the frontend, I created a page for each of the careers. I want a scenerio whereby if one should go to page named "Programmer" for example, one would be shown all the authors that check "Programmer" in their profile. The authors info like avatar, name and links to all posts would be shown in a loop

I don't know how to go about it. Hoping you guys here can assist with this.

-------------------------------EDITED---------------------------

With the help provided by @AustinWinstanley thus far, here is my code

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'career', 'meta_value' => 'programmer' ) );

if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
```

With the above query, any author whose career field's value is programmer is listed. The above code is suitable if the value field for Career is an input field. I don't intend to make career's value to be an input field, rather I want it to be checkboxes where authors can check multiple values.

Since it's not going to be an input field, but rather checkboxes, how do I edit this line to reflect what I want?

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'career', 'meta_value' => 'programmer' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to [query users by meta data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Examples). Something like this:

```
// Set this value by whatever you're searching for
$career = 'programmer';

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'career',
                'value'   => $career,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                // Or 'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    )
 );
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

$result = $wp_user_query->get_results();
```

Edit:

For the front end form:

```
<form method='post'>
    <input name="careers[]" type="checkbox" value="programmer"> Programmer
    <input name="careers[]" type="checkbox" value="accountant"> Accountant
    <input name="careers[]" type="checkbox" value="manager"> Manager
    <button name="career-search">Search</button>
</form>
```

In your plugin or function/includes:

```
function careers_postback( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() && isset( $_POST['career-search'] ) ) {
        $careers = $_POST['careers']

        $meta_query = array();

        foreach( $careers as $career ) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'career',
                        'value'   => $career,
                        'compare' => '='
                    )
                )
            );
        }

        $args = array(
            'meta_query' => $meta_query
         );
        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

        $result = $wp_user_query->get_results();

        set_query_var( 'search-career-results', $result );

        // Here you would include your search template and call exit
        // In your template, use `get_query_var( 'search-career-results')
        // Then check if there are results and list them if there are.
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'careers_postback' );
```

This is in general. I haven't fully tested it because I'm not typing it in an editor. But this is the full solution to check boxes and get users by their meta data using the data. If this doesn't work in general, then you are doing something you aren't revealing. Like not saving careers to user meta data.

Comment: I got an error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in ........ on line 31` What I want is to be able to show all users that have selected or checked "programmer" as their career. I want to show them in a loop. Thanks for your time

Comment: `Career` isn't a standard option. The error you're getting is because there are no results. How is the career data being saved? As a meta key? Is the value an array? You're going to have to change the answer to your use case. There isn't enough information to know exactly how the meta data is being saved, but this is an example of how to search for users using a meta key and value.

Comment: Seems you didn't get my gist. I want to show a list of authors who have entered or selected programmer in a page. If for example there are two authors who have selected "programmer" as their career, those two authors should be shown in the page. Thank you for your time again

Comment: Yea, that part is covered by this solution. It's getting all the users that have the career like programmer (or whatever you provide. This will return those. As of now, it's not returning any results. The query is wrong because I'm not sure how you're saving the 'programmer' value to the user. If it's being saved as a meta value, then this will do it. It seems it's being saved in a different way. Maybe as an array? Without info on how you're saving the `career` to the User, I can't help with the exact query.

Comment: Thank you once again. I have edited my question. I will appreciate your help with in finding solution to this

Comment: The code is the same. The checkboxes just determine the input for the query. The [link I provided](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Examples) shows how to include multiple values. You just need the checkbox group on the front and provide the post values. Is that the part you're missing? Getting the data from the frontend to the backend?

Comment: I just added the frontend for you. I haven't tested it. If this isn't what you want, then I have no idea what you're asking.